# Couchdb not starting. -- Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse

Tags: erlang, couchdb, port, ubuntu-10.04, couchdb-futon

I have configure and installed couchdb 1.6.1 on ubuntu 10.04. While configuring and installing it said successfully done. But when I start couchdb it gives me error.

**When start first..**

```
Apache CouchDB 1.6.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.

Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.

**[info] [<0.32.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://127.0.0.1:5984/**
```

**When starting again**

```
 Apache CouchDB 1.6.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.

 **Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse**

[error] [<0.127.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                    {<0.127.0>,crash_report,[[{initial_call,
                           {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                       {pid,<0.127.0>},
                       {registered_name,[]},
                       {error_info,
                           {exit,eaddrinuse,
                               [{gen_server,init_it,6},
                                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                       {ancestors,
                           [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,
                            <0.32.0>]},
                       {messages,[]},
                       {links,[<0.95.0>]},
                       {dictionary,[]},
                       {trap_exit,true},
                       {status,running},
                       {heap_size,987},
                       {stack_size,24},
                       {reductions,467}],
                      []]}}
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1},{application_master,start_it_old,4}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

in local.ini I changed 
**Port to 5983 and also ip to 0.0.0.0 from 127.0.0.1**
Nothing helped

When i run sudo netstat -tulpn

I get following output

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21688/beam.smp

**couchdb -s** says **Apache CouchDB is not running**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does curl `http://localhost:5984/` give you any response?

Comment: Hello Akshat thanks for reply, It doesn't give me any response... i guess waiting to connect  couchdb -s says Apache CouchDB is not running.

Comment: You can manually kill couchdb with a utility like htop. Just install it.Type htop on terminal. Press F4 to search for couchdb and F9+enter to kill it. See if it helps.

Comment: `couchdb -d` will shut down CouchDB background processes.

Comment: @dethtron5000 Thanks for reply.. couchdb -d says Apache CouchDB is not running.

Comment: Try to avoid 0.0.0.0 as host, or you are sure you want to have a public accessable CouchDB. Try to kill all the processes listening on Port 5984 and make sure they are _gone_. If that does not help, wait a little bit - that has helped my sometimes, when a port has not been freed by a program correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you came here because you recently upgrade you CouchDB 2.0, make sure you updated your local.ini config file. The section for the web server configuration has changed (the name changed from something like `httpd` to `chttpd`). Because of that the port directive wasn't being picked up and it was defaulting to 80 which was the same as the web server.

Comment: I've found that if you had *both* chttpd and httpd set, you'd get this error.    Commenting out the httpd section worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! upgrading from v1.x to 2.x, this was definitely the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message entries provided, CouchDB is already up & running on your machine/ server with port 5984

```
**Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse**
```

That's why When you run **sudo netstat -tulpn** command on Linux based machine, you are getting the following output :

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5984 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 21688/beam.smp
```

**Solutions :**

couchdb is not a service script in the way you're trying to use it. It is just trying to start up again and failing because one is already running (erlang beam.smp process is still running).

Check & kill all CouchDB processes using following commands :

```
/bin/ps aux | grep couchdb | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs killl
```

Start CouchDB again using following command using `root` linux user :

```
service couchdb start
```

**Note :**

- When you enter **couchdb -s** command, You are getting the message like `Apache CouchDB is not running.`
- When you enter **couchdb -d** command, You are getting the message like `Apache CouchDB is not running.`

Reason for above outputs, You are executing above mentioned commands as non privileged linux users accounts.

Try to execute above mentioned commands as `root` Or couchDB running linux users accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced same problem. I just did..

`sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

Note:i just re-installed couchdb now it's working fine. before re-install i did below configuration.

Install ICU and use locate to find the icu-config command:

```
locate icu-config


sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

for more details refer below link

https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem...

Luckily there's a fix in the Couchdb Error messages documentation.
https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages

**Problem**

$ couchdb
Apache CouchDB 0.9.0a747640 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1},{erl_eval,do_apply,5},{erl_eval,exprs,5},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}

**Solution**

Edit your /etc/couchdb/couch.ini file and change the Port setting to an available port.

But mine didn't have couch.ini but had default.ini.
I changed that to another port that i guessed should be free and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error in starting couchdb on ubuntu 16.04

The reason being erlang running on the port 5984, you would be something like below when running the command "netstat -tulpn"

0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13967/beam.smp

open the file /etc/couchdb/default.ini in super user mode and change the httpd port to some other port which is available and you would be able to start couchdb without any fail.